# How to build associations/records in models using after_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a user model

```
has_many :trial_subscriptions
accepts_nested_attributes_for :trial_subscriptions, :allow_destroy => true 
attr_accessible :trial_subscriptions_attributes
```

the trial_subscription inherits from subscription model and this model `belongs_to :user`
the subscription model `belongs_to :question_bank` and question bank model `has_many :subscriptions, dependent: :destroy`

I have a form that is creating a user and its posting correctly.

I want to add an `after_create` callback

with a method that starts the trial subscription for the user and the question bank for the subscription after the user creation has been detected.

1) am I doing the call back in the user model or the trialsubscription model? I am doing it in the trialsubscription model

here is the method so far

```
class TrialSubscription < ManualSubscription

  after_create :create_trial_subscription_for_all_qbanks

  def create_trial_subscription_for_all_qbanks
    if !trial_account_made_by.nil? #in User 
      QuestionBank.all each do |q| 
        TrialSubscription.create!(question_bank_id: q.id, user_id: self.id, manual_expiry_date: Time.now + (2*7*24*60*60) )
      end 
    end 
  end 
end
```

in my rails c after I submit a new user in my form, I keep on doing

```
a = User.last
a.trial_subscriptions #returns an array
```

I think the `create!` should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Put the callback into your `User` model:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :trial_subscriptions

    after_create :create_trial
    def create_trial
       QuestionBank.all each do |q| 
           self.trial_subscriptions.build({question_bank_id: q.id, manual_expiry_date: Time.now + (2*7*24*60*60)})
       end
       self.trial_subscriptions.save
    end
end
```

Comment: I didn't try this but my way actually works but I was doing it in the wrong model.

Comment: I was getting an undefined method save from your way? but I think your way works too.

Comment: Yes I think it will need to be assigned to an instant variable or similar (needs some more thought)